# Encoding with requests in python

Tags: python, python-requests

Came across a strange issue.

I am passing a dictionary as part of a POST request to a cgi script:

```
self.settings = {
    'SubmitCommands': ['C:\Python27\python.exe path\my_script.py']
}
```

Here is my code:

```
    settings = self.settings

    # Make web call to CGI script
    user_agent = r'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'
    headers = {'User-Agent' : user_agent, "Accept": "text/plain"}
    response = requests.post(
            "path\CGI\cgi_script.py", 
            headers=headers, data=settings)
```

And here is the resulting traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path\CGI\cgi_script.py", line 119, in initi
alizeJob
    self.submitCommands = eval(inputSubmitCommands)
  File "<string>", line 1
    C:\Python27\python.exe path\my_script.py
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

However, if I do this the old fashioned way I do not get the traceback:

```
    settings = self.settings

    # Set and encode parameters
    params = urllib.urlencode(settings)

    # Make web call to CGI script
    user_agent = r'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'
    headers = {'User-Agent' : user_agent,
                "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "Accept": "text/plain"}
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(self.host)
    conn.request("POST", "path/CGI/cgi_script.py", params, headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
```

Earlier today someone warned me on Stack Overflow for picking a library just because it is new.  Looks like I should have listened to them.   However, I am still curious about what went wrong.

Comment: Is the parameter to `requests.post` and `conn.request` actually a path? Or is it a URL?

Comment: The parameter is a path.

Comment: That's very odd. On my machine, when I try using a path (`requests.post("/tmp/CGI/cgi_script.py")`), I get `MissingSchema: Invalid URL u'/tmp/CGI/cgi_script.py': No schema supplied`.

Answer (score 2):

Python is interpreting your backslashes as escape codes. Just double them up to fix that.

```
self.settings = {
    'SubmitCommands': ['C:\\Python27\\python.exe path\\my_script.py']
}
```

Comment: or use a raw string r'C:\Python27...'